# Why do these parenthesis move when trying to find a vertex form?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, curves

Can someone explain to me why when expanding this vertex form equation does the $ah^2$ term get included with the $+k$ part?

As far as I can see it's a product of expanding the $a(x-h)^2$ part.

[image]

I can only presume it's to keep the form $ax^2+bx+c$.

tvm

Comment: Your presumption is correct. The next step is probably to derive formulas for h and k in terms of a, b and c by comparing coefficients.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct, $(ah^2+k)$ is just a constant, so we slap it into the position of $c$!